# Auctex command on region - backward search leads to region.tex instead of main.tex

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search, aquamacs, pdfsync

In `auctex` I can run a command only on a certain region to speed up compiling.
This works great, however if then I use the backward search to jump from the `.pdf` to the `.tex` source code, it opens the temporary `_region_.tex` file instead of my real tex file `chapter2.tex`.

I did search on the internet and in the auctex documentation, but did not find a hint how to set this up correctly.

### Some hints about the configuration

#### LaTeX master file with included chapters

I'm using a master file (let's call it `main.tex` and then include a source file for each chapter with e. g.

```
\include{chapter2}
```

#### *Region*.tex file and corresponding log file

My `_region_.tex` file contains the following line directly after `\begin{document)`

```
\message{ !name(chapter2.tex) !offset(927) }
```

which I think should be used for exactly this purpose.

The `_region_.log` file contains a line, which refers to the master file, not the chapter:

```
**\input _region_.tex
(./_region_.tex  !name(main.tex)
```

#### PDF viewer sync settings

In the preferences of `Skim.app` (the pdf viewer) I'm using the following configuration:

- command: `emascsclient`
- arguments: `--no-wait +%line "%file"`

#### System and software versions

I'm using MacOS X 10.6 and TeXLive 2014, `AUCTeX 11.88`.
My pdf viewer is `Skim.app` and my source editor is `Aquamacs.app` (Version 3.2)

(*I've updated to Aquamacs 3.2 which uses AUCTeX 11.88, but I still have the same problem*)

Comment: IIRC, if you use Evince, the current development version of AUCTeX brings back to the original document.

Comment: thanks! How can I determine the installed version of auctex? I'm not using `evince`, but Skim.app on `MacOS X`

Comment: `C-h v AUCTeX-version`, but you'd know if you were using the development version of AUCTeX, you'd have compiled it by yourself `;-)`

Comment: thanks, no I'm not using the development version, but 11.87. So you mean, this just should not work in v 11.87? You're right, I did not compile it myself in this case, but you would not imagine what I've already done or configured and then forgot about having it done... :-)

Comment: @giordano: in `auctex v11.88` it still does not work for me (is your version newer than 11.88?), but I found a solution in the auctex mailing list (see my answer below)

Comment: The development version is the version after the last stable one (11.88 currently).  And I said it works only with Evince, you use Skim instead.  Good to see you found a solution anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution for that by configuring `emacs` (aquamacs):

source: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.general/4285

```
(defadvice server-goto-line-column (after server-visit-region.tex
                                         (line-col)
                                         activate)
 "When visiting _region_.tex from an external
source (e.g. inverse search), go to the original file so that any
changes made won't be lost."
 (when (string-match "_region_.tex\\'" (buffer-file-name))
   (if (save-excursion ;; in case we don't find the other file we at least want the right line...
         (re-search-backward
          "\message{ !name(\\([^)]+\\))\\(?: !offset(\\([-0-9]+\\))\\)?\\s *}" nil nil))
       (let ((file-name (match-string 1))
             (offset (match-string 2))
             (line (car (ad-get-arg 0)))
             (col (cdr (ad-get-arg 0))))
         (if offset (setq line (+ line (string-to-number offset))))
         (find-file file-name nil)
         ;; For some reason this doesn't actually go to the offset
         ;; line.  It's probably because of how advice works.
         (server-goto-line-column (cons line col))
         (message "Moved from _region_.tex to line %s of %s." line file-name)
         (forward-line offset))

     ;; else
     (message "This is _region_.tex, but I couldn't find the original file!"))))
```